# Animating a sine wave infinitely

Tags: c, animation, trigonometry

I need a function to animate a sine wave infinitely over time. The sine wave moves to the left.

My sine wave is built using the following equation:

```
A * sin(B * x + C) + D
```

Now to animate the sine wave as if it is moving to the left, I simply increase C by 1 everytime I refresh the screen. Now this is all fine and dandy for a few minutes but I need to have that animation run for hours. I can't just have an integer build up 60 times a second forever. How does someone deal with this? Do I just try to find a point where the sine wave crosses 0 and then restart the animation from 0?

I just need to have the logic of something like this explained.

**EDIT #1**
I forgot to mention that there's a randomized component to my sine. The sine is not continuously the same. A and D are sinusoidal functions tied to that integer at the moment. The sine needs to look random with varying periods and amplitudes.

**EDIT #2**

Edited see Edit 3

**EDIT #3**

@Potatoswatter I tried implementing your technique but I don't think I'm getting it. Here's what I got:

```
        static double i = 0;
        i = i + (MPI / 2); 
        if ( i >= 800 * (MPI / 2) ) i -= 800 * (MPI / 2);

                    for (k = 0; k < 800; ++k)
        {
            double A1 = 145 * sin((rand1 * (k - 400) + i) / 300) + rand3;       // Amplitude
            double A2 = 100 * sin((rand2 * (k - 400) + i) / 300) + rand2;       // Amplitude
            double A3 = 168 * sin((rand3 * (k - 400) + i) / 300) + rand1;       // Amplitude

            double B1 = 3 + rand1 + (sin((rand3 * k) * i) / (500 * rand1));     // Period
            double B2 = 3 + rand2 + (sin((rand2 * k) * i) / 500);           // Period
            double B3 = 3 + rand3 + (sin((rand1 * k) * i) / (500 * rand3));     // Period

            double x = k;                               // Current x

            double C1 = 10 * i;                         // X axis move
            double C2 = 11 * i;                         // X axis move
            double C3 = 12 * i;                         // X axis move

            double D1 = rand1 + sin(rand1 * x / 600) * 4;               // Y axis move
            double D2 = rand2 + sin(rand2 * x / 500) * 4;               // Y axis move
            double D3 = rand3 + cos(rand3 * x / 400) * 4;               // Y axis move


            sine1[k] = (double)A1 * sin((B1 * x + C1) / 400) + D1;
            sine2[k] = (double)A2 * sin((B2 * x + C2) / 300) + D2 + 100;
            sine3[k] = (double)A3 * cos((B3 * x + C3) / 500) + D3 + 50;

        }
```

How do I modify this to make it work?

Halp!

Answer (score 2):

Sine has a period of 2 pi, meaning that `sin(x) = sin(x + 2 * M_PI)`, for any `x`.

So, you could just increase `C` by, say, `pi/n` where `n` is any integer, as you refresh the screen, and after `2n` refreshes, reset `C` (to `0`, or whatever).

**Edit for clarity:** the integer `n` is not meant to change over time.

Instead, pick some `n`, for example, let's say `n = 10`.  Now, every frame, increase `x` by `pi / 10`.  After `20` frames, you have increased `x` by a total of `20 * pi / 10 = 2 * pi`.  Since `sin(x + 2 * pi) = sin(x)`, you may as well just reset your `sin(...)` input to just `x`, and start the process over.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately my math skills are slightly lacking so I'm wondering if you could clarify your answer a bit. Wouldn't increasing C by pi / n where n is a continuously growing integer slow the animation down over time since the result returned would grow increasingly smaller?

Comment: Or you mean like n is a constant here? For instance 4800 and then reset to zero after 9600 frames?

Comment: @ReX357 yes, exactly.

Comment: -1, Moving by exactly `pi/n` is unnecessarily restrictive. There's no need to require him to change the animation speed.

Comment: Does it need to be 2n or it can be any even number of n? ie: 4n, 6n, 8n, etc.

Answer (score 0):

`sin` is periodic, with a period of 2π. Therefore, if the argument is greater than 2π, you can subtract `2 * M_PI` from it and get the same answer.

Instead of using a single variable `k` to compute all waves of various speeds, use three variables `double k1, k2, k3`, and keep them bound in the range from 0 to 2π.

```
if ( k2 >= 2 * M_PI ) k2 -= 2 * M_PI;
```

They may be individually updated by adding some value each frame. If the increment may be more than 2π then subtracting a single 2π won't bring them back into range, but you can use `fmod()` instead.

Comment: I see what you mean. However, if you notice, my C (x shift) is tied to variable i not k. All the sines have sinusoidal equations to define A and D so it looks very random over time. I tried the solution that said to increase i by pi / n and then resetting after a multiple of 2n but it simply skips to a totally different set of waves when I wrap back to 0. Does this still apply to a wave with varying amplitude and y shift over time?

Comment: To elaborate a little more on k, my view port is 800 pixels wide. I iterate through an array that's 801 values long (Extra value is cause I run a line_to function to draw the line) where each value is y. K is simply x position in my line basically. i is elapsed time basically. Gets updated 60 times a second.

Comment: @ReX357 I get it. My best-practices advice would be to keep everything clipped into [0, 2π) because as floating-point numbers grow they lose precision. So, keep three versions of `i`, and use them to initialize three versions of `k`, and constrain all the `i`'s and `k`'s in both the inner and outer loops.

Comment: I'm sorry I keep quizzing you, I'm just trying to wrap my head around the whole thing here. I still don't understand how I need to initialize 3 versions of k? k is 0 to 800 no matter what. It represents 1 pixel no matter what. I use it in my equations to create some movement in the graph. Are you saying I should leave it out of the equations and simply use i where i is between 0 and 2pi?

Comment: @ReX357 You can increment `k1`, `k2`, `k3` 800 times, and each increment represents one pixel. I'm saying to calculate the increment, and add that much to each `k` rather than calculating everything from a single integer which tends to grow. But of course you can also have a separate `int k` if that's what the graphics library expects. Anyway… When things get confusing, I like to write down the equation in comments and simplify using basic algebra.

Comment: I still don't get it. I updated my code in edit 3 after fiddling around for a while. I'll pay you if you turn my code into working code. No joke.

Comment: @ReX357 It looks like you gave `i` storage as `static` and changed some constants, but I don't see the line of code I suggested. I'll just edit the question with a quick ifx.

Comment: Think I'm starting to get it. You mean basically, maintain a unique i for each sine and reset to 0 when it's appropriate for the particular sine. And each separate i should stay within the range of 0 to 2pi. Is that correct?

Comment: Oh, never mind. I need to go, and the quick fix isn't so quick because you really do need to declare separate `double` variables to define the phase of the various waves.

Comment: @ReX357 Yes, that is right. My edit to the question is wrong and i'll revert it, hold off on editing for a sec.

Comment: So I gave up and used my other tactic. I just use the monotonic clock to drive i. Works like a charm.

Comment: @ReX357 *"I'll pay you if you turn my code into working code. No joke"* - consider offering a bounty instead: http://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty

Answer (score 0):

I decided to change my course of action. I just drive `i` with the system's monotonic clock like so:

```
        struct timespec spec;
        int ms;
        time_t s;
        static unsigned long long etime = 0;

        clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &spec);
        s = spec.tv_sec;
        ms = spec.tv_nsec / 10000000;
        etime = concatenate((long)s, ms);
```

Then I simply changed `i` to `etime` in my sine equations. Here's the concatenating function I used for this purpose:

```
unsigned concatenate(unsigned x, unsigned y) {
    x = x * 100;
        return x + y;        
}
```